# SQL Server database table name in sp_addextendedproperty

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

does anyone know how to set explicitely the name of the database when calling the stored procedure sp_addextendedproperty.

This call so far works

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The display order of the right' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'_right', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'display_order'
```

How can I add the database name, if I want to loop certain databases and add fields
Let's say I have a database 'Test' and a database 'Production' and in a loop I want to execute the stored procedure for Test and Production database, how can I add them to the stored procedure call?

Comment: You can't. `sp_addextendedproperty` like most system procedures targets the current database. Use `USE somedatabase` to switch databases or the undocumented but globally used `sp_MSForEachDB` stored procedure to run your script against all databases, one by one

Comment: Silly me, you're absolutely right, I should use USE DATABASE instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to assign the value of the procedure you want to execute to a variable. This means you can concatenate the name of the database prior to the name of the procedure (`sys.sp_addextendedproperty`) and then execute it in the context of the database:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo._right(display_order int);
GO
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @DBName sysname = N'Sandbox';

DECLARE @ProcName nvarchar(255) = QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.sys.sp_addextendedproperty';

EXEC @ProcName @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The display order of the right' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'_right', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'display_order'
GO
USE Sandbox;

SELECT *
FROM sys.extended_properties EP

GO
DROP TABLE dbo._right;
```

If you need to do this against multiple tables you could either loop through the values or create a dynamic SQL statement. I demonstrate the injection method here. I *assume* your object names are coming from a table type parameter here (but define a variable in the example).

```sql
DECLARE @DBs table (DBName sysname);
INSERT INTO @DBs
VALUES(N'Sandbox'),(N'Utility');

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(DBName) + N'.sys.sp_addextendedproperty @Name, @Value, @level0type, @level0name, @level1type, @level1name, @level2type, @level2name;', @CRLF)
FROM @DBs;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'@Name sysname, @Value sql_variant, @level0type varchar(128), @level0name sysname, @level1type varchar(128), @level1name sysname, @level2type varchar(128), @level2name sysname',
                       N'MS_Description',
                       N'The display order of the right',
                       'SCHEMA',
                       N'dbo',
                       'TABLE',
                       N'_right',
                       'COLUMN',
                       N'display_order';
```

For a loop, you would execute the procedure like the first example.